# Segmented mailing list tool?

Tags: email, mailing-list

I'm looking for a mailing list tool which lets me group contacts into lists, and lets me choose which lists to send a message to for each message I send. The most important feature is that some contacts are on multiple lists, and I don't want them to receive duplicate messages. Also, it's important that the group name not be revealed to them; the sender should be myName@example.com or annoncements@example.com and the recipient should be announcements@example.com or the recipient's own email address.

I want email groups like this:

- Concerned citizens
- Out-of-town
- Really important people
- News reporters

I have a single ~1000-person email list right now via [GNU Mailman](http://www.list.org/), and I want to be able to continue sending plenty of emails to the first group to keep them informed and engaged, while only emailing the other groups when its really important or relevant to them.

I have a strong preference for open source solutions, but free commercial solutions or even paid commercial solutions are acceptable if they are *substantially* better. I have shared website hosting with SSH access.

Some of the mailing list tools I've looked at include [Sympa](https://www.sympa.org/overview/features), [GroupServer](http://groupserver.org/groupserver/), and [Groups.io](https://groups.io/static/features). I'm not seeing the precise feature I'm looking for, but maybe it has a name I don't recognize.

Comment: We use Lyris at work as a listserv management software, it allows this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you also look at [Mautic](https://www.mautic.org).

- For organising lists into categories, see [here](https://www.mautic.org/docs/en/categories/categories.html)
- It is open source, so you can self-host.
- Also take a look at the mautic forums for various tips/plugins

[Phplist](https://www.phplist.org/) is another alternative to look at.